# ENOENT: no such file or directory for node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

I am following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a), but I keep getting the following error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\andrewkp\Documents\VSCode\Projects\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\andrewkp\Documents\VSCode\Projects\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Here is my angular.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyProjectName": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyProjectName",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProjectName:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyProjectName:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProjectName:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyProjectName-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyProjectName:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyProjectName"
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After reviewing my error carefully:

> C:\Users\andrewkp\Documents\VSCode\Projects\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

I noticed that I was navigating to far back, as I can see above the path it is trying to read from is totally wrong, not including my project name at all.

The fix was to change:

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```

To:

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```

Comment: Exactly the same happened to me, hard to spot until I found your post

Comment: Awesome!Thank you for this!

Comment: ran into similar issue when including bootstrap

Comment: it didn't work for me, I've checked jquery.min.js is inside that folder and it is, I also changed the routes, but everything remains the same